# Use the to-be-continuous kubernetes template for an existing cluster GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gitlab, to-be-continuous

I am currently using your [to-be-continuous Kubernetes template](https://to-be-continuous.gitlab.io/doc/ref/kubernetes/) and I want to deploy a Kubernetes manifest inside a cluster (Google Kubernetes Engine in GCP) that is previously created (in another gitlab project).

The problem is that I need to have the credentials of the GKE cluster first (a command to execute). It's only after that I can set the KUBECONFIG variable with the context.

What i tried is to get the credentials of the GKE first in a before_script job :

gcloud container clusters get-credentials sample-cluster --location=us-central1-f

And store the content inside the KUBECONFIG variable, but the gitlab CI crashes because it wants the KUBECONFIG variable to be set.

Is there any way to set it after the before_script job without the CI to crash?

Thanks